# Duplicate clustered observations and create a unique identifiers for the duplicated clusters

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rep

Consider the small dataset df1. There are 5 clusters identified by ID, row_numbers contains a unique value for each observation and weights identifies how many copies we want to each cluster.

```r
df1 <-data.frame(ID=c("10","20","30","30","30", "40", "40","50","50","50","50"), row_numbers = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),weights=c(4,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2))
df1
#>    ID row_numbers weights
#> 1  10           1       4
#> 2  20           2       3
#> 3  30           3       2
#> 4  30           4       2
#> 5  30           5       2
#> 6  40           6       3
#> 7  40           7       3
#> 8  50           8       2
#> 9  50           9       2
#> 10 50          10       2
#> 11 50          11       2
```

The expected output is df2
The most important part of df2 is the new variable "newID". The unique identifiers for the duplicated clusters are stored in newID where newID will identify the clusters by using consecutive integers starting from 1.

```r
df2 <-data.frame(ID=c("10","10","10","10","20","20","20","30","30","30","30","30","30", "40", "40","40", "40","40", "40","50","50","50","50","50","50","50","50"), row_numbers = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11),weights=c(4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), newID= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14))
df2
#>    ID row_numbers weights newID
#> 1  10           1       4     1
#> 2  10           1       4     2
#> 3  10           1       4     3
#> 4  10           1       4     4
#> 5  20           2       3     5
#> 6  20           2       3     6
#> 7  20           2       3     7
#> 8  30           3       2     8
#> 9  30           3       2     8
#> 10 30           4       2     8
#> 11 30           4       2     9
#> 12 30           5       2     9
#> 13 30           5       2     9
#> 14 40           6       3    10
#> 15 40           6       3    10
#> 16 40           6       3    11
#> 17 40           7       3    11
#> 18 40           7       3    12
#> 19 40           7       3    12
#> 20 50           8       2    13
#> 21 50           8       2    13
#> 22 50           9       2    13
#> 23 50           9       2    13
#> 24 50          10       2    14
#> 25 50          10       2    14
#> 26 50          11       2    14
#> 27 50          11       2    14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a split-apply-bind approach:

```r
df3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), function(x) 
{
  group_size   <- nrow(x)
  n_groups     <- x$weights[1]
  if(is.na(n_groups)) n_groups <- 1
  if (n_groups < 1)   n_groups <- 1
  
  group_labels <- rep(paste(x$ID[1], seq(n_groups)), each = group_size)

  x <- x[rep(seq(group_size), each = n_groups), ]
  x$newID <- group_labels
  x
}))

df3$newID <- as.numeric(as.factor(df3$newID))
df3 <- `rownames<-`(df3, seq(nrow(df3)))
```

Which matches your expected output:

```r
df3
#>    ID row_numbers weights newID
#> 1  10           1       4     1
#> 2  10           1       4     2
#> 3  10           1       4     3
#> 4  10           1       4     4
#> 5  20           2       3     5
#> 6  20           2       3     6
#> 7  20           2       3     7
#> 8  30           3       2     8
#> 9  30           3       2     8
#> 10 30           4       2     8
#> 11 30           4       2     9
#> 12 30           5       2     9
#> 13 30           5       2     9
#> 14 40           6       3    10
#> 15 40           6       3    10
#> 16 40           6       3    11
#> 17 40           7       3    11
#> 18 40           7       3    12
#> 19 40           7       3    12
#> 20 50           8       2    13
#> 21 50           8       2    13
#> 22 50           9       2    13
#> 23 50           9       2    13
#> 24 50          10       2    14
#> 25 50          10       2    14
#> 26 50          11       2    14
#> 27 50          11       2    14
```

And we can show this is identical to your desired result:

```
identical(df2, df3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I tried to apply this on my huge dataset but I did not get the desired output in terms of the newID.

Comment: @Victoria where did it go wrong? This algorithm does what you described and works for the example you provided. It's difficult to know what further we can do to help without a counterexample of where this doesn't work. Are you able to find it?

Comment: @Victoria now I'm confused. Can you explain why row 10 has 8 as a new ID?

Comment: @Victoria and why do all the repetitions of the first cluster get new ids but the repetitions of other clusters share the same ids?. Are you sure you don't just want newID to be a sequence of 1:27?

Comment: newID is the unique identifier that identifies the clusters using consecutive integers.(based on the number of times an ID is repeated in df1). In df1, ID=10 occurs once and we duplicated it four times, so we have 1,2,3,4. ID= 20 occurs once as well in df1 and duplicated 3 times, so corresponding to the newID is 5,6,7 (because newID has to be a consecutive integer). ID = 30 is repeated 3 times in df1, and duplicated twice each in df2, so the newID for the first ID=30 is 8,8,8, for the second ID=30, is 9,9,9 and the third ID=30 is 10,10,10.

Comment: No, I don't want it as a sequence of 1:27. The newID I am trying to create corresponds to the newcl created here https://www.coursehero.com/file/p3a1207/expandcl-replaces-each-cluster-in-the-dataset-with-n-copies-of-the-cluster/

Comment: @Victoria you say "so the newID for the first ID=30 is 8,8,8, for the second ID=30, is 9,9,9 and the third ID=30 is 10,10,10." but this is not what your expected output shows in your example at all. Could you double check your expected output please?

Comment: oh sorry, the expected output is correct. I explained it wrongly.  There are 3 rows with ID =30 in df1 with weight =2 assigned to each of them. This was replicated into 6 rows in df2. ID=30 is repeated 6 times in df2, but the newID asigned has to be repeated integers consecutively repeated n times the number of times ID appears in df1

Comment: for instance also, ID = 40 is repeated twice in df1 with weights =3 assigned to them ->we have 6 rows in df2, but in newID the sequence of the integers are repeated twice continuously because ID== 40 appeard twice in df1

Comment: @Victoria I have changed it so it now matches your expected output. Note it will also handle NA and 0 values as specified in your linked document. If this has solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a solution with data.table :

```
library(data.table)
df1 <-data.frame(ID=c("10","20","30","30","30", "40", "40","50","50","50","50"), row_numbers = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),weights=c(4,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2))
dt1 <- data.table(df1)

# with .x a data.table with cols : ID, row_numbers (integer), weight (integer) 
duplicate_weight <- function(.x) {
  # get the part to keep unchanged
  untouched <- list(
    .x[is.na(weights), .(ID, row_numbers, weights = 1, repetition = ID)] , 
    .x[weights == 0, .(ID, row_numbers, weights = 1, repetition = ID)],
    .x[weights == 1, .(ID, row_numbers, weights = 1, repetition = ID)]
  )
  # list of the weights > 1
  weights_list <- sort(unique(.x[['weights']]))
  weights_list <- weights_list[weights_list > 1]
  # repeat accordingly to weights
  repeated <- lapply(weights_list, # for each weight
                     function(.y) { 
                       rbindlist( # make a data.table
                         lapply(1:.y, # repetead .y times
                                function(.z) { 
                                  .x[weights == .y, .(ID, row_numbers, weights = 1, repetition_position = .z)])
                                }
                         )
                       )
                     } 
  )
  
  result <- rbindlist(c(untouched, repeated))
  setorder(result, ID, repetition_position)
  result[, new_id := .GRP, by = .(ID, repetition_position)]
  result[, repetition_position := NULL]
  
  result
}

duplicate_weight(dt1)
```

It's similar to @Allan Cameron

Comment: Thank you. I reedited the question. I am simply only now interested in generating newID.I have managed to exclude weights with NAs and  zeros